# highcharts.js custom chart implementation

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I need to implement such simple chart using JS https://i.stack.imgur.com/6gusX.png
I reviewed highcharts.js lib, but I couldn't find ready solution or sinilar chart.
If someone know tool that can help to implement it, please help.

Comment: It would help if you posted a code sample of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be done using Highcharts.

To **format the markers** use the following code.

```
plotOptions: {
    // means all series types, you can change it according to the serie type
    series: {
        marker: {
            radius: 8,
            fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: null
        }
    }
}
```

[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnVAR/)
[reference](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.marker.lineColor)

Then to **add the point value inside the marker**.
I'll use the previous code, as example.
By default, `dataLabels` are disabled, so you have to `enable` and then set it's `y` position.

```
plotOptions: {
    // means all series types, you can change it according to the serie type
    series: {
        marker: {
            radius: 12,
            fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
            lineWidth: 2,
            lineColor: null
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            y: 13,
            // default formatter
            formatter: function() {
                return this.y;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I changed the radius value because it's too small to put a number inside, you can use `formatter` to format it's number.
[**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnVAR/1/)

Then you have to **style xAxys labels**.

```
xAxis: {
    labels: {
        style: {
            color: 'orange',
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            'font-size': '20px'
        }
    }
}
```

And [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/VnVAR/2/) is the result.
Of course it's not perfect. But it can be, I was just trying to show you that's **it's possible to do it using Highcharts** and you have a **lot of options** and a good [**reference**](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#plotOptions.series.dataLabels.formatter) that can help you.